# ubuntu kde terminal font is misplacing the cursor and some other characters with custom fonts

Tags: terminal, fonts

so briefly I downloaded the operator mono font used as the default one for the desktop and some other programs but it seems to not go well with the terminal 
NOTE: i didn't put any space there , it's just it misplaced away from the 'o' in "too"
 [image: misplaced characters screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font! This (for me) is absurd to have italic, script font as terminal font. Fount some monospace, sanserif font and use it.

And the reason for such behavior is bad [kerning pairs](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/using-type-tools/spacing-and-kerning-1) design. You can correct it by editing the font itself